# Regex: Extract a single named match from two values separated by inbetween characters?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I have the following content (two fields with separators):

```
~12.8~oz~
```

I need to have a single named match that holds the pair minus the ~ (in ASP.NET C#):

```
~(?<size>\d+\.\d*~[^~]*)~
```

This of course matches 12.8~oz instead of 12.8 oz.  And yes I would love to replace the ~ with a space.

Any suggestions?

Comment: uh.. why not replace the ~ with a space then?

Comment: You realize that `\d+` doesn't actually match `12.8`?

Comment: If you want *one* match without the tilde in it, that is not possible. However, it is very easy to remove with another line of code.

Comment: Lower in the code, the Regex object's named properties are Mapped to same named object properties.

Comment: Map it in another way. I don't think that is possible. In .Net, you can have one Match with two Captures, but I doubt that helps you. Maybe you can replace *before* you capture? Replace `(~\d+\.\d*)~([^~]*~)` with `$1 $2`, and then match `~(?<size>\d+\.\d* [^~]*)~`

Comment: This seems awfully contrived to me. Why can't you just replace the ~ with a space? Or change the code below, or, or, or...? When you have to try to come up with a clever way to make the framework do something, that's generally a code smell that the reason for needing the clever hack is because the surrounding code is too inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about replacing the string?

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"~(\d+\.\d*)~([^~]*)~", @"\1 \2");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // 
}
```

Or, in the regex just above, of concatenating Group 1, Space, then Group 2?